# when clicked print coordinates from Points in array

Tags: java, arrays, point

I want to print out the X and Y coordinates from 3 Points in a array.
When clicked on the JFrame, the coordinates of that click need to go to the first Point p1, the second click to the second Point p2 and third click to p3.
This is my code:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
Point[] points = new Point[3];
p1 = points[0] = e.getPoint();
p2 = points[1] = e.getPoint();
p3 = points[2] = e.getPoint();
System.out.println(p1 + p2 + p3);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am i doing wrong?"* - Primarily: Posting incomplete code with an unclear question. You should extend the question and state what the actual problem is.

Comment: Please post any relevant error messages and be careful about trimming out code necessary for your sample to compile.

Comment: alright, thx for the feedback <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put points outside of moussepressed

```
Point[] points=new Point[3];
int i=0;

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    if(i==0){
        points[0]=e.getPoint();
    }else if(i==1){
        points[1]=e.getPoint();
    }else if(i==2){
        points[2]=e.getPoint();
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the above answer, you can do the following:

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    if(points.size() < 3)
       points.add(e.getPoint());
}
```

Then... points.get(0), points.get(1), points.get(2)  will get you the three points.

Your code posted is adding the same three points to a Point array every time your mouse is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Point[] points = new Point[3];
    Point p1 = points[0] = e.getPoint();
    Point p2 = points[1] = e.getPoint();
    Point p3 = points[2] = e.getPoint();
    System.out.println(p1.toString() + p2.toString() + p3.toString());
}
```

You can use too a StringBuilder to concatenate your points:

```
System.out.println((new StringBuilder()).append(p1).append(p2).append(p3));
```